# Custom post type REST api 404: Updating failed. No route was found matching the URL and request method

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, 404-error, wp-api, post-type

I have registered a new post type as:

```
$this->sconfig= ['post_type'=> 'event', 'slug'=>'events'];
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_event_posttype'));
```

and

```
function register_event_posttype()
    {
        //unregister_post_type($this->sconfig['post_type']);
        $args= [
            'labels' => [ 'name' => __('Events'), 'singular_name' => __('Event')],
            'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats'],
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu'=> true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'=> true,
            'exclude_from_search'=> false,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $this->sconfig['slug']),
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'rest_base' => $this->sconfig['slug'],
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            //'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller'
        ];
        register_post_type($this->sconfig['post_type'], $args);
    }
```

Now this url (http://localhost/install05/wp-json/wp/v2/events/114?_locale=user) gives a 404 status with output (triggered when trying to save draft custom post):

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

[image]

Note: I have some custom meta fields associated with this post type and they are appearing fine in the add/edit page.

---

**What I tried so far (without results):**

**#1:** Unregistering and registering the custom post type and flushing the rewrite rules (re-saving the permalink structure)

**#2:** Changing to this (in case of conflict): `$this->sconfig= ['post_type'=> 'my-event', 'slug'=>'my-events'];`

**#3:**

Defining the custom route:

```
function rest_route_for_events($route, $post) {
        if($post->post_type === $this->sconfig['post_type'] ) {
            $route = '/wp/v2/'.$this->sconfig['slug'].'/' . $post->ID;
        }
        return $route;
    }
add_filter('rest_route_for_post', array($this, 'rest_route_for_events'), 10, 2);
```

Thanks for reading this far and some more for giving some thoughts over it :).

Comment: "*triggered when trying to save draft custom post*" - is it your `event` post, and how did you save the post? Did you do it via JS, PHP, or was it done via the block-based post editor when you edit the post? If you did it programmatically, then what is your code and how/when/where did you run it?

Comment: I was trying to save from wordpress admin (block editor).

Comment: **I tried your code and it worked fine for me** - I didn't get the error in question when saving a draft `event` post via the block editor. So try deactivating plugins and/or your other custom code, and see if the same issue persists. But, how did you check for that error, and did the editor show that or any error? Maybe you can share one or two screenshots (showing the error)?

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/yYSQAbI.jpg

Comment: Many thanks to you for trying in your system.

Comment: Tried with default 'Twenty Twenty-Two' theme (w/o any plugin) without luck. Examining further.

Comment: Finally got it. Posted as answer. So many thanks for your intervention.

Answer (score 3):

The registration code was called inside the `is_admin()`. Moving the code outside solved the issue.

```
/*if(is_admin())
{*/
$this->sconfig= ['post_type'=> 'event', 'slug'=>'events'];
add_action('init', array($this, 'register_event_posttype'));
/*}*/
```

Comment: It never crossed my mind you'd do that admin check , so +1  But, did you do that intentionally, and if so, why?

Comment: Unless I give the information in the question, it is impossible for anyone to figure that out . I did it on premonition to save execution time by not reloading the setup codes every time the application loads.